# Query for finding possible "Not An Answer" posts

Tags: sql, stackexchange

I have [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/220414/possible-naa-not-an-answers) in SEDE to try to find possible not an answers to flag. *<sup>(I already went through a lot of them, for Stack Overflow, so I don't really recommend anyone else using this one since isn't that helpful anymore.)</sup>*

As you can see, it looks to be a lot longer and redundant than it probably needs to be. Is there any way to shorten this?

```
SELECT
    p.Id as [Post Link],
    len(p.Body),
    p.CreationDate as Date
FROM
    Posts as p
JOIN
    Users as u
ON 
    p.OwnerUserId = u.Id
JOIN
    Posts as q
ON
    p.ParentId = q.Id
WHERE
    u.Reputation < 126
  and
    len(p.Body) < 300
  and
    p.Body LIKE '%a href=%'
  and
    p.Score < 3
  and
    p.PostTypeId = 2
  and
    p.CommentCount < 3
  and
    q.ClosedDate IS NULL
  and
    q.FavoriteCount < 3
  and
    q.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%plugin%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%plugin%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%plug-in%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%plug-in%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%tool%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%tool%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%framework%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%framework%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%API%'
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%API%'
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%IDE%'
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%IDE%'
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%library%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%library%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%cms%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%cms%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%open source%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%open source%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%application%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%application%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%software%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%software%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%tutorial%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%tutorial%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%book%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%book%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%module%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%module%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%resource%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%resource%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%engine%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%engine%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%lightweight%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%lightweight%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%opensource%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%opensource%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%technologies%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%technologies%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%simulator%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%simulator%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%compiler%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%compiler%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Body NOT LIKE '%editor%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
  and
    q.Title NOT LIKE '%editor%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
ORDER BY
    len(p.Body) ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, I would avoid using `JOIN` on it's own. `INNER JOIN` should be used instead, it's much easier to understand what is happening at a glance if you see `INNER JOIN` over `JOIN`

I would capitalise the `AS` and `AND`'s, it just makes it more consistent.

Otherwise, the general formatting is pretty nice.

I would maybe argue that the table aliases are a little unnecessary, `Posts` and `Users` are already pretty short and are more meaningful than the single letter aliases you gave them. I would consider aliasing the joined `Posts` table `Answers` or something similar.

Lastly, the largest point. You are checking if both the body and title do not contain the same string. You can concatenate body and title together, with a space to separate them, and check for the word/phrase you are searching for in that instead, effectively halving the size of your where statement.

```
SELECT
Posts.Id AS [Post Link],
LEN(Posts.Body),
Posts.CreationDate AS Date

FROM Posts

INNER JOIN Users
ON Posts.OwnerUserId = Users.Id

INNER JOIN Posts AS Answers
ON Posts.ParentId = Answers.Id

WHERE Users.Reputation < 126
AND LEN(Posts.Body) < 300
AND Posts.Body LIKE '%a href=%'
AND Posts.Score < 3
AND Posts.PostTypeId = 2
AND Posts.CommentCount < 3
AND Answers.ClosedDate IS NULL
AND Answers.FavoriteCount < 3
AND Answers.CommunityOwnedDate IS NULL
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%plugin%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%plug-in%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%tool%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%framework%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%API%'
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%IDE%'
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%library%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%cms%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%open source%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%application%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%software%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%tutorial%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%book%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%module%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%resource%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%engine%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%lightweight%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%opensource%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%technologies%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%simulator%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%compiler%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
AND Answers.Body+' '+Answers.Title NOT LIKE '%editor%' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

ORDER BY LEN(Posts.Body) ASC
```

[Here is the SEDE Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/223356/possible-naa-not-an-answers?opt.withExecutionPlan=true)